# Direct limit of Cyclic Groups

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, limits-colimits

With the usual order $I=\mathbb N$ is a directed set.

Suppose that for each $i\in \mathbb N$ we have a subset $\{s_i\}$ of real numbers, such that for each $i\leq j$,   $s_i\mathbb Z$ is a subgroup of $s_j\mathbb Z$ and the inclusion homomorphism are the transtition maps $\varphi_{ij}:s_i\mathbb Z\rightarrow s_j\mathbb Z$.

Then the direct limit is  subgroup of $\mathbb Z$ right? because each $s_i \mathbb Z$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z$ and the direct limit is identified with a subgroup of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: No, not necessarily. For example if $s_j = \frac{1}{2^j}$ then the colimit is $\mathbb{Z} \left[ \frac{1}{2} \right]$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan the limit in this case is dense in the real numbers right?

Comment: In my opinion the term "direct limit" is deprecated and should be avoided, because it is not a limit at all in the modern sense but a colimit. And yes.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan if the real numbers $\{s_i\}$ are integers then the colimit is discrete isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ right? thanks

Comment: If the $s_i$ are integers then your sequence eventually stabilizes, since $n\mathbb{Z}\subseteq m\mathbb{Z}$ (with $m,n$ integers) if and only if $m\mid n$, and there is no infinite descending chain of integers in the divisibility order. In that case, the colimit is just the stable group you eventually get. I doubt that is what you want.

Comment: "each $s_i\mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$, right?" Wrong, unless every $s_i$ is an integer already, in which case see the previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for real numbers $a$ and $b$, if $a\mathbb{Z}\leq b\mathbb{Z}$ then $a\in b\mathbb{Z}$, so there exists an integer $n$ such that $a=nb$; if $a\neq 0$, then this means that $b=\frac{1}{n}a$.

Any $0$ term forces all previous terms to be $0$; if all terms are $0$, you just get $\{0\}$. If at least one term is nonzero, we may assume that it is $s_1$. So assume $s_1\neq 0$.

Then there must exist integers $n_1,n_2,\ldots$ such that
$$\begin{align*}
s_2 &= \frac{1}{n_1}s_1\\
s_3 &= \frac{1}{n_2}s_2 = \frac{1}{n_1n_2}s_1\\
&\vdots
\end{align*}$$
Dividing through by $s_1$ we may assume that what you have is
$$\mathbb{Z}\supseteq\frac{1}{n_1}\mathbb{Z}\supseteq\frac{1}{n_1n_2}\mathbb{Z}\supseteq\cdots \supseteq \frac{1}{n_1\cdots n_k}\mathbb{Z}\supseteq\cdots$$

The colimit/union that you get is:
$$\left\{\frac{a}{b}\in\mathbb{Q}\;\Bigm|\; \gcd(a,b)=1\text{ and there exists }k\text{ such that }b\mid n_1\cdots n_k\right\}$$

(Okay, "really" it's the set of all $\frac{s_1a}{b}$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$, etc. but we may as well take $s_1=1$ to look at the structure...)

Indeed, if $\frac{a}{b}$ is as given, then let $c$ be such that $bc=n_1\cdots n_k$. Then $\frac{a}{b}= \frac{ac}{n_1\cdots n_k}\in \frac{1}{n_1\cdots n_k}\mathbb{Z}$.

Conversely, every element of $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n_1\cdots n_k}\mathbb{Z}$ is rational; if $\frac{a}{b}$ lies in the union, with $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then there exists $k$ and an integer $m$ such that $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{m}{n_1\cdots n_k}$. This gives that $b\mid n_1\cdots n_k$, as desired.

In particular, if the sequence $|n_1|,|n_2|,\ldots$ is eventually constant $1$, you get a group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, since you get $\frac{1}{N}\mathbb{Z}$ for some integer $N\gt 1$.

If the sequence is not eventually constant $1$, then the resulting group cannot be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, as it contains fractions with arbitrarily large denominator, hence it cannot be a cyclic subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$.